# DIY Christmas SFX - any ideas?

Tags: sound-design, foley, sfx, tips, diy

I'm putting together a guide on how you can make your own Christmas SFX using common household objects. I've got a list of ideas going already, but I'm still looking for ideas for making various sounds such as:

- Sleigh bells (without having actual sleigh bells at hand)
- Sleigh ride
- Gift opening and shaking
- Snowball fight
- Winter wind
- Tree felling
- Christmas cooking (roasting and sauce bubbling)
- Christmas ornaments ringing
- Chimney gliding (for Santa's house entry)
- Santa Footsteps

The plan is to list fun, novel ways of creating Christmas sound effects using just what everyone has laying about in their house.

So if you've got ideas for these - or other Christmassy sounds - please let me know.

The guide will be published on [A Sound Effect](http://www.asoundeffect.com) and you'll of course be credited with your idea.

Really looking forward to hearing your ideas!

Best,
-Asbjoern

**UPDATE:** The guide to making your own Christmas sound effects is now out - [check it out here](http://www.asoundeffect.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-making-your-own-christmas-sound-effects/), and thanks to everyone who shared their ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Cellotape - I think it would sound very christmas-like if you layer some bell jingling with cellotape being stretched out for gift wrapping :)

For the gift shaking I would use a shoe box and fill it with various types of objects for example:- plastic toys, DVD cases, coins etc. Then shake the box with various degrees of excitement!

In terms of tree felling - Ive designed a tree falling sound before by taking the sound of cellotape being stretched out and then slowing it right down. I forget the parameters for the time-stretch, but its good to experiment with different speeds and pitches. Eventually it should sound like a thick tree cracking and falling.

Again, great idea! If it turns out well, maybe it can be done for other seasonal holidays? Im loving the A Sound Effect site and its newsletters.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks - and really glad you like A Sound Effect too! :)

Comment: Stubert91, please drop me a note on A Sound Effect and let me know your real name so I can credit you in the final guide :)

Answer (score 0):

More ideas :

- Reindeer call
- Christmas market ambience
- Fireplace sounds
- Christmas goblins/elves vocalizations
- Toy's sounds

All the best, this guide is a great idea!

Comment: Just realized it was just sounds that can be made with household objects, so no christmas market or reindeer calls (or imitated by mouth or with objects). :)

Comment: Yeah - but some very good ideas for a general Christmas SFX library though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Food:
- Sizzle of meat roasting
- Crackling of pork skin roasting

Heat:
- Crackle of wood burning
- Kettle whistling
- Coal being raked

Life:
- Baby cooing
- Children running down/up stairs

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't *have* to be things you have in the house - just everyday objects that are easy to come by. Let me give a few examples:

- A crackling fireplace: Could be done with a bag of potato chips being being slowly squeezed/compressed or bubble wrap being squeezed/twisted
- Walking in snow: Could be done with flour, corn starch or salt in a bucket

etc - hope this gives you an idea of what I'm thinking of :)

Answer (score 0):

HoHoHo - Created by using a combination of your throat, your tongue, your teeth, vocal strings and your lips. :)

Comment: Now there's a very unique approach :D I'll go practice immediately!